# R Markdown - Customize TOC html

Tags: css, r, markdown, r-markdown

I add a TOC to my HTML document and use the following CSS to style it. But I can't close the blue gap in the picture below? I don't find the right property.

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XInx.png)

```
<style type="text/css">
.main-container {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#TOC {
  margin: 20px 0px 1px 0px;
}
@media (max-width: 1800px) {
#TOC {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
}


.toc-content {
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-right: 1px;
}

div.main-container {
  max-width: 100%;
}

div.tocify {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 85%;
}

@media (max-width: 1800px) {
  div.tocify {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: It's not possible to definitively answer your question without you also including the markup that these styles are targeting. Your best bet would be to include your markup and styles in an editable codesandbox that reproduces the issue.